# How to migrate legacy customers over to SPO the easy way (Q&A)

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

So I was in ESPC22 and managed to eliminate an entire class of work for me in SPO development. Namely writing migration scripts for legacy customers to import all their data into SPO with little to no effort.

The primary problem for me was Lotus Notes migration. To say it was painful is an understatement.

NOTE! - I have not had the time to try it out for my self as of yet and I will soon. However any answer that will give a step-by-step guide over mine I will accept!

Answer (score 0):

So the lecture was about big data. Namely how to do big data analytics with [Azure Synapse Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/synapse-analytics/#overview)

So the big take away is that there are 3 big data formats that big data uses: CSV and two more that are kind of irrelevant.

But CSV is something that we can almost always get from legacy systems. In Lotus Notes you get XML, but writing a CMD helper that converts an XML to CSV is trivial at the best of times (in C# .NET at least).

So the thing you do not get it that in big data you have this concept of SQL Lake. What that is is basically a SQL instance that you can connect to any application to do what ever you want and whom data source is a CSV file (or any other common big data file type).

So here is what you do:

1. Convert all legacy data to CSV
2. Spin up SQL Lake connected to a CSV file with Azure Synapse
3. Use MS Access (yes Access) to connect to SPO and the SQL Lake instance and do the migration
4. Kill the SQL Lake instance

NOTE! - The #4 is important, because Azure Synapse is really expensive, but in the mean time before migration you can always use the instance to show the client exactly what will be migrated etc.

[Tutorial on how to use Access to migrate SQL data to SPO](https://www.kalmstrom.com/tips/sharepoint-online-course/import-data-from-sql-to-sharepoint-online.htm)